# Conditionally supply ASP.NET Identity OAuth token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin

I'm using a ASP.NET Identity OAuth token to log in my Xamarin forms user. I would like to have the token be provided only when a specific bool column in the AspNetUser table is true.

This bool column is essentially asking "Is this user allowed to log into the Xamarin app?: Yes/No".

Is there a way to achieve this using tokens?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of the token itself? There is only a token, if a user is logged in.